# Could not find installable ISAM when mapping to network

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

This is my aspx.vb code and I am connecting to an access database on the specified server. I have put the connection string as per Network Location (mdb file) as per given on https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/network-location-mdb-file/

```
    Protected Sub btnSave_Click1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim connectionString As [String] = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\135.2.219.70\DataImport\VQT.mdb"

        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        conn.Open()

        conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't use a proper connection string. You have `;Data" + " Data Source`, which clearly is wrong. The property isn't `Data Data Source`, it's `Data Source`. Remove the `Data" + "` that follow the `;`. (And learn to read the code you copy and paste and understand what it's doing.)

Comment: Thanks for the help Ken its shooting this error now \\135.2.219.70\NLV-MOS\DataImport\VQT.mdb' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides. I have shared the folder on the server which contains the .mdb file.

Comment: Then it's not a valid path. Can you browse to that specific file using that path in Explorer from the same location that your aspx code will be running on? (IOW, not necessarily the computer you're sitting at, but the machine your *application* will be running on, using the same credentials your app is using.)

Comment: The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\\135.2.219.70\DataImport\VQT.mdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data. 
Yeah I have done that the path is valid.

Comment: I don't know what you're looking for here. The message *cannot open* you quoted is clear. Either the file is opened exclusively by someone else, or you don't have rights to access that location from the account your app is using. We can't troubleshoot your access rights to that location from here. The path may be valid *for you, from where you're sitting and with your credentials*. Read my last comment again related to *the machine your app is actually running on, using the same credentials your app is using*. That's not the account you're logged in with, and not necessarily the same PC.